# Как связать таксономию и категорию?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Как связать таксономию и категорию
/category/vse-skidki/tovary/ - тут выводятся записи в категории
я создал таксономию 
/location/moscow/

Теперь задача такая сделать ссылку такой

/category/vse-skidki/tovary/location/moscow/

или /location/moscow/category/vse-skidki/tovary/

для того чтобы отфильтровать записи в категории по городу

Как это сделать подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: категория (=рубрика) и есть таксономия. По русски - [систематизация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%8F). То что ты хочешь - подрубрики

Answer (score -1):

`/%category%/`, `/%tag%/`, `/%author%/` и `/%postname%/`. Можно использовать, например, `/blog/%category%/%postname%/` или `/%year%/%postname%/` написано в кодексе, указывается в пункте Меню> Настройки> Постоянные ссылки, выбираете чекбокс "произвольно" и указываете последовательность которая вам подходит например: `site,ru/%category%/%tag%/%postname%/`

Comment: Исправьте ответ, напишите его как-то более понятно и с учетом правил русского языка. Теги кода я вам добавил.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста как это по вашему отфильтрует записи в категории по таксиномии?